# Undefined property: App\Services\UserService::$app in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to instantiate a singleton class in Laravel:

```
namespace App\Services;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserService{
//code
$friendRequestService = $this->app->make(FriendRequestService::class);;
```

I get this error:

> Undefined property: App\Services\UserService::$app

Comment: You need to post your whole UserService content.

But I can already see that you're trying call an app property of your service. You can do it from service provider if it is inherited from Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.

Comment: please check the post's update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use laravel helper to instantiate a class from the Container:

```
app()->make();
```

Comment: it becomes like this ? : $this->app()->make(FriendRequestService::class);

Comment: The thing that it doesn't and it shouldn't. When you call $this, you call your current class. You can access app Class as a property from certain classes only (such as Providers). But this one is presumably your custom class.
However, laravel developers made a helper (basically a globaly available function), which you can call from anywhere.